# How do i get multiple button id which i am displaying through php?

Tags: php, jquery

I am querying and displaying list of posts which also have buttons. I am trying to get the button ID when clicked. Its running on console but failing from editor.

`php:` testDisplay.php

```
include('../../common/database.mysqli.php');

        $conn = new common();
        // $page= $_POST["page"];

        $query = $conn->get_query("SELECT * FROM test_posts");
        $count = $conn->find_no_rows($query);
        $output .= '<ul id="inserted-data">';
        if ($count > 0) {
            while ($results = $conn->fetch_assoc_array($query)) {
            $output .= '<li class="data-list">'. $results['post'] .'
                                        <button class="data-delete" id="del-'. $results['id'] .'">Delete</button>
                                        <button class="data-update" id="edit-'. $results['id'] .'">Update</button>
                                    </li>';
            // echo $results['id'];                     
            }
            $output .= '</ul>';
        }
        
        echo $output;
        //inserting this ul inside other class through jQuery below
```

`jQuery:`
this is bringing php data and loading through ajax
`

```
function loadPost(page){
        $.ajax({
            url: "include/testDisplay.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {page:page},
            success: function (data) {
                $('.other').html(data);
            }
        });
        
    }
    loadPost();
```

;`

this gives me ID in console but failing in editor -

```
$(".data-delete").bind('click', function(){
            console.log(this.id);
        })
```

Comment: What is `in editor`?

Comment: Hi, this `data-delete` is dynamically generated so you need to bind it with static parent ..i.e : `$(document).on("click",".data-delete",function(){ //you codes })` .Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) post .

Comment: The problem description is a bit hard to understand here, but I’m guessing this is just the usual problem, of “statically” bound event handlers not applying to elements, that have been added to the document later. And the general solution for that is called _event delegation_, so go and read up on that.

Comment: @Swati Thanks, It worked. For any dynamically generated element we need it grab it by `$(document)` ?

Comment: @user3783243 i mean from local `code` editor.

Comment: It can be any element which is already present in your `DOM` i.e : `body,any div..etc` .Go through link which i have added in my previous comment to know more .